# Hadoop 2.6 multinode clustering

Tags: hadoop, high-availability

i am having 2 namenodes and 4 datanodes.namenodes acts itself as datanode and dedicated 2 other datanodes also.when i tried

lsof -i:2181 -s

it shows namenode1/x.x.x.x -> namenode1 on namenode1 and
namenode2/x.x.x.x -> namenode2 on namenode2.
when i check automatic failover by killing pid of activ namenode both web UI stops and shows error logs for `hadoop dfwsadmin -report` are 
in namenode2 ==>>>

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Call From namenode2/10.7.1.65 to namenode2:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFsStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getStats(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDiskStatus(DFSClient.java:2360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:937)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getStatus(FileSystem.java:2254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.report(DFSAdmin.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.run(DFSAdmin.java:1763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.main(DFSAdmin.java:1941)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 19 more
15/09/01 10:57:03 WARN retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getStats over namenode1/10.7.1.73:8020. Not retrying because failovers (15) exceeded maximum allowed (15)
java.net.ConnectException: Call From namenode2/10.7.1.65 to namenode1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFsStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getStats(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDiskStatus(DFSClient.java:2360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:937)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getStatus(FileSystem.java:2254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.report(DFSAdmin.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.run(DFSAdmin.java:1763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.main(DFSAdmin.java:1941)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 19 more
report: Call From namenode2/10.7.1.65 to namenode1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused


**on namenode1** == >> 

java.net.ConnectException: Call From namenode1/10.7.1.73 to namenode2:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFsStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getStats(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDiskStatus(DFSClient.java:2360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:937)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getStatus(FileSystem.java:2254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.report(DFSAdmin.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.run(DFSAdmin.java:1763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.main(DFSAdmin.java:1941)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 19 more
15/09/01 11:32:51 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking getStats of class ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB over namenode1/10.7.1.73:8020 after 3 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 3172ms.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From namenode1/10.7.1.73 to namenode1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFsStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getStats(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getStats(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDiskStatus(DFSClient.java:2360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:937)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getStatus(FileSystem.java:2254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.report(DFSAdmin.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.run(DFSAdmin.java:1763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSAdmin.main(DFSAdmin.java:1941)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 19 more
15/09/01 11:32:55 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking getStats of class ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB over namenode2/10.7.1.65:8020 after 4 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 5263ms


jps for namenodes before failover ===>>>

namenode1 :::

14187 NodeManager

13959 DFSZKFailoverController

12974 JournalNode

14051 ResourceManager

15270 Jps

12543 NameNode

13480 DataNode

namenode2 :::

9569 DFSZKFailoverController

9699 NodeManager

10731 Jps

8958 JournalNode

8946 NameNode

9278 DataNode


please help me
```

Comment: How did  you configure two namenode ? Federation or High Availability ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check your configuration files.

### **core-site.xml**

**fs.defaultFs**

http://asdfg (logical url)

**ha.zookeeper.quorum**

h1.c1:2181,h1.c2:2181,h1.c3:2181 (list of quorum)

### **hdfs-site.xml**

**dfs.nameservices**

asdfg

**dfs.ha.namenodes.asdfg**

nn1,nn2
....
....

[see this link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html)

Answer (score 0):

Restart both the name nodes and check once. If issue still persists, check if the Name node directories are accessible and logs of the namenodes(active and standby - as it will give the precise information to be resolved). If nothing works, format those name nodes.                          hadoop namenode -format

It should work.